# Is there any way to check who execute query?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure, database-performance

I have db on Azure. In Query Performance Insights every day I get same query in top 5 long running queries. It is `SELECT Id FROM MyTable` query.

I thought it can be my code, so I have added `Include` to include records from `MyTable` to queries (work with EF, no lazy loading). But this doesn't help.

Have checked also store procedures, but also no luck (cannot find any place where `MyTable` can be used).

Can I get place who can call this SELECT query on my side?

---

From `sys.query_store_plan` I can grab query_plan, but this doesn't help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=sql-server-2017)  it seems you should be able to run a trace on Azure databases. Assuming proper filtering options it might help you out where the query comes from or at least when it runs. (Disclaimer: I have no personal experience with it)

If you want to know what objects might be using the table you can either look in `sys.sql_dependencies` or in `sys.sql_modules`. The former is easier to query but might miss dependencies due to the order of deploying objects and/or the use of dynamic SQL. The latter has better chances in that department, but it's a bit of a hack and probably will give false positives.

```
SELECT Object_Name(object_id) FROM sys.sql_dependencies WHERE referenced_major_id = Object_Id('<table name>')
SELECT Object_Name(object_id) FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE '%<table name>%'
```